# how to change the number of harmonics for THD in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I am learning to work with LTSpice. After I did my transient analysis, I established the .four command, but I don't know how to change the number of harmonics from the default which is 9 in LTSpice, any insights are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought of first consulting the most immediate resource available: the help? It's rather spartan, but I believe you'll find most of what you need in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.FOUR -- Compute a Fourier Component after a .TRAN Analysis

Syntax: .four <frequency> [Nharmonics] [Nperiods] <data trace1> [<data trace2> ...]
```

If we define [Nharmonics] ,then analysis includes that (Nharmonics) number of harmonics.

Example
.four 1kHz 50 V(out)
It will find THD with 50 harmonics.

Reference: http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=FOUR_dot_command